# Airmon-ng не существует | Aircrack-ng

Tags: windows, cmd

Скачал недавно aircrack-ng на Windows, а там нет airmon-ng. Что делать в этой ситуации?

Изначально планировал на Linux делать, но VirtualBox шлет сетевые интерфейсы нахер, поэтому пришлось перейти на винду. (Нет возможности скачать linux)

Comment: А оно вообще на винду портировано?

Comment: Нет возможности **скачать**? Ты на диалапе сидишь?

Comment: @donRumata, сеть плохая. Скорость от силы 100-200кб. Серфить инет сойдет, но качать что-то быстро не получается. Требовалось решить прямо на месте, поэтому я скачал aircrack-ng, но не нашел там airmong, поэтому написал сюда.

Comment: 100кб - это дорхрена, если ты знаешь принци работы торрента. Вот когда у тебя диалап по гостю - вот это да, фигово. https://www.kali.org/downloads/ качай через торрент, пиши на флэшку и не парь мозг.